# whether $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$

Tags: ring-theory

How to check whether $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z?$

My guess: If $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is reducible then $$x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=f(x)g(x)$$ where $1\le\deg f(x),\deg g(x)\le3$ and $\deg f(x)+\deg g(x)=4$

Checking all the cases for $\deg f(x),\deg g(x)$ is a lengthy exercise. Is there any other way?

Comment: If you allow "Cyclotomic polynomials are irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$..." Then you are done..

Comment: Yes, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) Eisenstein's criterion .
Note that $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 = x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\ldots + 1$ for the prime $p=5$.

Comment: I knew Cyclotomic polynomials are irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x].$ Does it hold for $\mathbb Z?$

Comment: You should be able to see that a polynomial which is irreducible in some field is irreducible in any of its sub ring.... *Edit after Pablo's comment :D

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use Eisenstein then :

Suppose it is reducible then you have only two choices (Why ??)
$$(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)=(x^2+ax+1)(x^2+bx+1)$$

or $$(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)=(x^2+ax-1)(x^2+bx-1)$$

This would not take more than two minutes to verify if $a,b$ are in $\mathbb{Z}$ in this case..

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $\;x\to x+1\;$ , which in fact is an automorphism of the ring of pol's:

$$x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1\to x^4+5x^3+10x^2+10x+5$$

Now just apply Eisenstein with $\;p=5\;$ to the above right polynomial...